# javascript to display multiple search results as you type

Tags: javascript

I'm having a filter issue (I guess).  Please see the code and results below.

```
function getMake(value) {
    $.post("../../sql/addVehicleFind.php",{partialMake:value},function(data){
        $("#results").html(data);
    });
}
function getModel(value) {
    $.post("../../sql/addVehicleFind2.php",{partialModel:value},function(data){
        $("#results2").html(data);
    });
}


<input class="rounded" type="text" name="findMake" onkeyup="getMake(this.value)" placeholder="make" 
    <?php if(isset($vechileMake) && $vechileMake != '') {echo 'value="'.$vechileMake.'"';} ?>  />

            <div id="results" style="max-height:200px; overflow:auto; padding-left:55px; text-align: left" ></div>


<input class="rounded" type="text" name="findModel" onkeyup="getModel(this.value)" placeholder="model" 
            <?php if(isset($vechileModel) && $vechileModel != '') {echo 'value="'.$vechileModel.'"';} ?>  />

            <div id="results2" style="max-height:200px; overflow:auto; padding-left:55px; text-align: left" ></div>
```

My problem is when I put in values into the 2nd input box for 'getModel', I get a second round of results of 'getMake' as in the image below:

[image: link to the image]

I hope there's a solution to this dilemma.  Any help greatly appreciated.

Thank you so much in advance

Answer (score 0):

I am familiar with php but not with javascript.  Here I show how much of a newbie I am to programming.  It occurred to me today that I can filter the selections in the php code that the function calls upon.

Hope this helps someone in the same situation.